# Unattended SSRS Printing

Tags: reporting-services

I need to print an SSRS report unattended, with no popups and no command line calls.  I'm having a hard time finding an example that does not use third party rendering.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Here's something I found online:

This code is from begining and it is based on Visual studio 2008, MSSQL Server 2008 environment.

I hope you have installed MSSQL Reporting Services 2008 installed and configured, if not then let me know i'll guide you.

1) After configuring Reporting Services 2008, Go to `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS10_50.SERVER2K8\Reporting Services\ReportServer\bin and locate RSClientPrint.cab.`

2) Copy this .cab file to your website folder.

3) Create a myASPX.aspx page

4) Create a myHTML.html page

5) Create an IFRAME in myASPX.aspx with width="0",height="0" and source=".html"

6) Create an object tag with the following attributes like this:

```
<object id="RSCP" codebase="RSClientPrint-x86.cab#Version=2009,1600,100,1" 
classid="CLSID:5554DCB0-700B-498D-9B58-4E40E5814405" VIEWASTEXT>
```

7) Write the following code within the script tag in myHTML.html page

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
     function getPrint(){
         RSCP.MarginBottom = '12.7';
         RSCP.MarginLeft = '12.7';
         RSCP.MarginRight = '12.7';
         RSCP.MarginTop = '12.7';  // 
        RSCP.Print('http://MYSERVERNAME:8080/RS2K8', '%2fMYDIR%2fMYREPORTNAME(without extension)', 'MyReport');
     }
 </script>
```

8) Finally onload event of body

```
<body onload="getPrint()">
```

[Heres the reference](http://forums.asp.net/t/1671276.aspx/1)